# AVR interrupt - reset vectors handling in assembly

Tags: assembly, timer, interrupt, reset, avr

I am using **AVR ATmega16** and I am trying to implement *a counter that counts seconds*. I am using `timer0` in order to produce an interrupt every 1/16 sec on a loop that repeats 16 times. Given the frequency of the microprocessor (`f=4Mhz`) and the *prescaler* value (`=1024`) I calculate that I need to give the timer an initial value of `12`.

Here is the start of a sample code that I found on a textbook of mine:

```
.include "m16def.inc"
.equ start = 12
.equ loops = 16
jmp reset
reti (x16)    ;there will be needed a total of 16 reti's in order for the next
              ;instruction to be at 0x12 = 0d18 where the jmp instruction is placed at the 
              ;overflow interrupt handling routine of timer0
jmp TIM0_OVF
reti          ;other Handlers
```

Could please some explain what those two `reti` commands are actually doing? How do they work? What does the comment on the code mean?

*Let me inform you that on ATmega16 the `TIMER0_OVF` vector is on the `program memory address = 0x12`

Comment: If we assume that `reti (x16)` means "output 16 `reti` instructions", then its purpose is to fill up all the interrupt vector slots between `RESET` and `TIMER0_OVF` with something. Placing a `reti` in each of those slots seems like a good idea if you don't care about handling those interrupts, since it just means "return from the interrupt".

Comment: wow! it all makes sense. thanks a lot. you can post it as an answer if you please in order for me to accept it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the interrupt vector table of the ATMega16:

```
1 $000(1) RESET External Pin, Power-on Reset, Brown-out
Reset, Watchdog Reset, and JTAG AVR
Reset
2 $002 INT0 External Interrupt Request 0
3 $004 INT1 External Interrupt Request 1
4 $006 TIMER2 COMP Timer/Counter2 Compare Match
5 $008 TIMER2 OVF Timer/Counter2 Overflow
6 $00A TIMER1 CAPT Timer/Counter1 Capture Event
7 $00C TIMER1 COMPA Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A
8 $00E TIMER1 COMPB Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
9 $010 TIMER1 OVF Timer/Counter1 Overflow
10 $012 TIMER0 OVF Timer/Counter0 Overflow
11 $014 SPI, STC Serial Transfer Complete
12 $016 USART, RXC USART, Rx Complete
13 $018 USART, UDRE USART Data Register Empty
14 $01A USART, TXC USART, Tx Complete
15 $01C ADC ADC Conversion Complete
16 $01E EE_RDY EEPROM Ready
17 $020 ANA_COMP Analog Comparator
18 $022 TWI Two-wire Serial Interface
19 $024 INT2 External Interrupt Request 2
20 $026 TIMER0 COMP Timer/Counter0 Compare Match
21 $028 SPM_RDY Store Program Memory Ready
```

In the code you've shown, the first slot (`RESET`) is filled by the `jmp reset` instruction. The next slot you're interested in filling is `TIMER0_OVF`, but inbetween `RESET` and `TIMER0_OVF` there are 8 slots that you should fill with *something*. Filling them with `reti` (RETurn from Interrupt) instructions is probably sufficient if you don't care about handling those interrupts.

If we assume that `reti (x16)` is interpreted by this assembler as *"output 16 `reti` instructions"*, then this will take care of filling those 8 slots.  In case you're wondering *"why 16 instructions for 8 slots?"* - that's because each of those slots take up 2 *words* (enough to fit a `jmp` instruction), and the size of a single `reti` instruction is 1 word. So you fill each slot with two `reti` instructions, the second of which serves no real purpose.